# Java regex regionEnd

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that finds times at the beginning of a string.
I want to remove that part of the string so I'm using the regioEnd function but it sets the regioend to
the end of the line.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+.\\d+");
String line = "4:12testline to test the matcher!";
System.out.println(line);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
int index = matcher.regionEnd();
System.out.println(line.substring(index));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String line = "4:12testline to test the matcher!";
line = line.replaceFirst("\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}", "");
System.out.println(line);
```

output :
testline to test the matcher!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to use just `end()` instead of `regionEnd()`. The `end()` method returns the index of the first character past the end of whatever the regular expression actually matched. The `regionEnd()` method returns the end of the area where the matcher searches for a match (which is something you can set).

Comment: mmh no with that I only get
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available

Comment: Oh, well, don't forget to call `matcher.find()` to actually look for your regex.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you could simply use `.replaceFirst("\\d+:\\d+", "")`:

```java
String line = "4:12testline to test the matcher!";
System.out.println(line.replaceFirst("\\d+:\\d+", ""));
// prints "testline to test the matcher!"
```